# Does an unicode small subscripted for Alpha exist (similar to „ᵦ“ (U+1D66))? Or is there another way to get this char without HTML?

Tags: java, string, unicode, subscript

have to replace letters with subscripted letters in a Java software. Can not use HTML labels, but can rename the subjects using Unicode characters. Unfortunately i am not able to find a subscripted small alpha(the only char missing to succeed..). Does this unicode even exist? Or is there another way to get a small subscripted alpha? Thx in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: there's none https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts#Latin,_Greek_and_Cyrillic_tables

Comment: You should develop a markup language for that. Or you can use HTML, TeX, ReST, markDown, etc. Unicode doesn't consider subscripts are characters but just as representation (like bold, italic, courier, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think so. But anyway, the unicode character U+1D66 is member of the *Phonetic Extension* block ([ref.](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D00.pdf)). That means that you should not use it if you only want to write a normal Greek β (U+03B2) in a subscript text bloc.

Having same or close display does not mean that characters are the same. For example the German Eszett ß (U+00DF) is a totally different character...